# performing boolean operations using SOLR

Tags: solr

I want to perform boolean operations using solr (AND, OR, '-' (prohibit search)).

I have changed this parameter:

```
<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND" />
```

Earlier it was OR.

Also, I've tried using q.op and given it's value as AND.
So, ideally, a query "abc def" should be interpreted as "abc AND def" but it's not the case. It's still being interpreted as "abc OR def". So how can I achieve the AND functionality ?

Comment: Have you changed the default boolean operator in solrconfig.xml to AND?

Comment: Using <str name="q.op">AND</str>
Yes. Done.

Comment: Which query parser and solr version are you using?

Comment: Solr version 3.5. And I'm using Standard query parser.

Comment: Really really sure you're not using `dismax` or `edismax`?

Comment: Absolutely. I tried using dismax but have commented out that code now. Coz I got to know that dismax does not support boolean operators.

Comment: Did you restart the server after changing the default? If you did, go to the admin panel and type in your query, check the verbose debugging option and see how it ends up ultimately. OR or AND.

Comment: Yes, I restarted the server after making the changes. And I'm also using an NGramFilterFactory with minGramSoze=2 in my schema.xml file. So, any query with AND will get tokenized into AN ND AND.